# attributive clauses puzzle me a lot sometimes

Tags: clauses

Are the following two sentences interchangeable?

> "I keep her photo on my desk, which means I do not forget her.

versus

> "I keep her photo on my desk, meaning I do not forget her.

If not, how are they different?

Comment: "I keep her photo on my desk" does not actually have a meaning related to "I do not forget her".  From that point of view, the first form is a little less awful than the second.

Comment: As others have suggested, both are unlikely sentences. Have you ever seen or heard either of them?

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences have similar meaning although they might be used in different circumstances. The first sentence would be more appropriate when it is used as part of an imperative argument, whereas the second one would be better used in a description of the past.

Maybe its just me, but somehow I feel the second sentence is quite unusual.

Also, the proper version of the first sentence would be "I keep her photo on my desk, which means *that* I do not forget her".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two sentences are interchangeable and identical in meaning.  But they both sound a little awkward.  It might be better to write "I keep her photo on my desk so that I don't forget her".